# Box2D physics editor for complex bodies

Tags: physics, box2d, editors

Is there any editor out there that would allow me to define complex entities, with joins connecting their multiple bodies, instead of regular single body entities? For example, an editor that would allow me to 'define' a car as having a main body with two circles as wheels, connected through joints.

**Clarification:**

I realize I haven't been clear enough about what I need. I'd like to make my engine data-driven, so all entities (and therefore their Box2D bodies) should be defined externally, not in code.

I'm looking for a program like Code 'N' Web's [PhysicsEditor](http://www.physicseditor.de/), except that one only handles single body entities, no joints or anything like that. Like PhysicsEditor, the program should be configurable so that I can save the data in whatever format I want to. Does anyone know of any such software?

Comment: This might be useful: http://www.iforce2d.net/b2deditor/ although I have to say, asking to save in 'whatever format you want to' is a pretty tall order :)

Comment: @iforce2d I honestly don't think it's that tall of an order. You need to have an interface to some scripting language, and the user can can redefine the load and save functions through scripts.

Comment: ah, well that sounds reasonable - I was imagining a huge list of options in the save dialog where you could choose csv, xml, bson etc. But exposing every facet of the Box2D world to script is not a trivial undertaking either... I just spent six months doing exactly that (see the 'pro' version linking from the page above, it allows for exporters to be written in script like you are talking about).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may be interested in [Physics Body Editor](http://code.google.com/p/box2d-editor/). That's an open-source tool handling bodies with multiple fixtures.

A big update is in progress, and next revision will support complex dynamic objects made of multiple rigid bodies linked with custom joints, as well as a scripting support for directly testing your bodies.

Hope you'll like it ;)

[image]

Comment: Physics Body Editor is good but if it allows us to define joints as well, it will be perfect.

Comment: Hi Aurelien... thanks for this superb tool. I am wildly searching for such a tool to use with LibGDX. But found that this is noy yet released in ur blog. I am a newbie and have justed with game development in LibGDX. Would like to know ..what is the best way if I want to make Box2D based levels in LibGDX games. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It still doesn't have mentioned functionality...

Answer (score 5):

R.U.B.E. is fantastic:
https://www.iforce2d.net/rube/

Its just does what it should and is not restricted to specific game engines like levelhelper..

Answer (score 3):

The Box2D website does list 3 editors that could be useful to you.
http://www.box2d.org/links.html

One of the links is dead however.  I was only able to check this one out:
http://www.brainblitz.org/BoxCAD/

There is an option to dump to code that I tried, and it does in fact give you the Box2D code of whatever you built on screen.  Looks pretty decent.

Answer (score 0):

LevelHelper (www.levelhelper.org) has support for Box2D joints. Here's a tutorial to get your started: http://www.levelhelper.org/?tag=cocos2d

Answer (score 0):

I use level director (www.retrofitproductions.com/level-director) and PhysicsEditor by codeandweb.

Physics Editor will allow you to apply the physic properties and body shapes to each object and Level Director will allow you to import them and then setup the complex bodies and joints as needed.
Once done, Level Director allows you to export the data in pretty much any format you desire via a template.

Comment: Link-only answers die when the link changes somehow. Could you summarise the "why"?